# Is there a way i can copy this macro i made but have it change for the next tickbox

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, macros

I have made this macro to Select cell A3 copy the value and paste it into cell Y3. it then clears cell A3 as that's a dropdown box, by doing this the dropdown option can be now selected in A4.

```
CopyPasteDelete Macro

    Range("A3").Select
    Selection.Copy

    Range("Y3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Range("A3").Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    Range("Y3").Select

End sub
```

Is it possible that i can copy this macro have A3 change to A4 and Y3 change to Y4, and link it to another check box in Z4?

Or do i have to do it the hard way and copy it again and again changing the macro and adding another tick box?

Comment: Why not write the macro for a range and iterate through it?

Comment: sorry im real new to excel and macros is another thing, how could i do that then.

Answer (score 0):

If you base the relative positioning on wherever the current selection or active cell is, you can have any row's cells from columns A & Y perform these tasks.

```
Sub A2Y()
    Dim r As Long, sr As Long
    If Not Intersect(Selection, ActiveSheet.UsedRange) Is Nothing Then
        For r = 1 To Intersect(Selection, ActiveSheet.UsedRange).Rows.Count
            sr = Intersect(Selection, ActiveSheet.UsedRange).Cells(r, 1).Row
            Cells(sr, "Y") = Cells(sr, "A").Value
            Cells(sr, "A").ClearContents
        Next r
        Cells(r - 1, "Y").Select
    End If
End Sub
```

That will look at what cells you have selected and for each of them that are within the worksheet's *UsedRange*, it will take that row and move the value from column A to column Y and clear column A.

Comment: would that macro still work for lets say i have drop down selected in A5 which has not finished so the tick box can not be ticked, but if A6 has finished i can tick that box, and then have the text of A6 be put into cell Y6. will this macro still accept that. thanks for the help Jeeped

Comment: @James - I'm afraid I really don't understand what you are describing in your reply comment here. What have you tried, what were the results and how did that differ from what you were expecting? Are you simply wishing to avoid blank cells in column A? Try modifying the macro and if you have trouble, post back.

Comment: i got a run time error, A3 column is my drop down list which has a selection of cars dynamic so only one can can be selected at a time. Z3 has a tickbox to say this car has been returned, so i need to delete A3 to make that car come back into the drop down list, but still have a record of what car they had in Y3. so each tick box needs to run this command for its row. i used your macro it gave run time error when other cars were selected in A colomn

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, just define your range and offset properly

```
Sub test()
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Range("A1:A100")
   c.Offset(, 24) = c
   c.ClearContents
Next
End Sub
```

If you'd rather do it another way, you can iterate through the cells -

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
i = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For j = 1 To i
    Cells(j, "Y") = Cells(j, "A")
    Cells(j, "A").ClearContents
Next
End Sub
```